# CSS 100% Height Issue

Tags: html, css

I have a small site I'm working where basically everything is fixed except for the content area. I want that content area to expand all the way to the bottom of the browser window. When the site is first loaded at a screen resolution of 1024x768 it appears that it works but if you scroll down the copy continues but the colored background does not. I have searched for a solution but I've had no luck so far.

Here is a link to the site: [www.atriaseniorliving.com/cah/our_process.html](http://www.atriaseniorliving.com/cah/our_process.html)

Edit:

Here is the css I am using:

```
#copyContainer {
width: 1000px;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;

font-family: 'Droid Serif';
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
```

}

```
#mainCopy {
display: block;
width: 390px;
height: auto !important;
margin: 127px 0 0 0;
padding: 30px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
top:0;
left:505px;
right:0;
z-index:99;

-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, .6);
```

Comment: rather than linking to your site.  I would recommend placing your problem code in code blocks for others to review or perhaps even building a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of you code, it allows people helping to see exactly where your problems might be.

Comment: I see a vertical scrolling bar with blue background on top of the main graphic. Scrolls ok but it is overlapping the upper block. Try **display:block;** in your stylesheet. Using Firefox 16.02.

Answer (score 0):

affects the size of the padding the element.

your style probably this

```
display: inherit;
width: 390px;
height: auto;
margin: 127px 0 0 0;
padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 505px;
z-index: 99;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, .6);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, .6);
```

Comment: Removing the "bottom: 0;" makes it so it doesnt expand all the way to the bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `height:100%` incorrectly... `height:100%` is referring to the height of your browser window. And what you think happen when an inner element has bigger height that his parent? That's your case: **#mainCopy has bigger height than browser window and therefore bigger height than #copyContainer**. You just need to update few styles:

```
#copyContainer {
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-family: 'Droid Serif';
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 24px;
   height: 100%;
}
#mainCopy{
   display: block;
   width: 390px;
   margin: 127px 0 0 0;
   padding: 30px;
   float: right; //No need position:absolute
   bottom: 0;
   top: 0;
   left: 505px;
   right: 0;
   z-index: 99;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, .6);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(51, 51, 51, .6);
}
#middleContainer {
   width: 100%;
   background: #D9D9D9;
   position: absolute;
   top: 128px;
   z-index: -1; //Because the image was over the text
}
```

Another things you can do to improve your code:

- The header has no height. has not height
- You are using like 3 diferents nested wrappers
- To much use of `position:absolute` and `position:fixed` without need
- Instead of `with:1000px` use `with:960px`
- You are using `margin-top:xxx` instead `top:xxx` on absolute positioned divs

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'bottom: 0' from #mainCopy. Your element is positioned absolutely so it will only go to the bottom of its reference container which is #copyContainer.